# Show/Hide div based on select value using a child ref with dynamically updated choices using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

These select options are changed via a wordpress backend, as well as the following div tags.

What I need is for the corresponding div tag to show only when the select box is on that choice by what number child it is.

Example of code:

```
<form>
    <select class="select" name="SELECT_Mood_30">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="hap">Happy</option>
        <option value="sad">Sadness</option>
        <option value="ang">Angry</option>
        <option value="gru">Grumpy</option>
    </select>
</form>

<ul id="show-these">
    <li></li>
    <li>Happy huh?</li>
    <li>Why so sad?</li>
    <li>Everything will be ok!</li>
    <li>Cheer up!</li>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</ul>
```

So basically I would like jquery to be able to know which number child is selected and show the same number child in the li ID "show-these".

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<div>` as the parent of `<li>`.

Comment: ...but aside from that, http://WhatHaveYouTried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

```
var $ul = $('#show-these');
$ul.find('li').hide();

$('.select').on('change', function(){
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    var $ul = $('#show-these');
    $ul.find('li').hide();
    $ul.find('li').eq(index).show();

});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="show-these">
    <li></li>
    <li>Happy huh?</li>
    <li>Why so sad?</li>
    <li>Everything will be ok!</li>
    <li>Cheer up!</li>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/36PfL/)**

Comment: looks like it does work in fiddle.. can't figure out why it's not working on my site though..

Answer (score -1):

Guess this helps:

```
<select class="select" onchange="update(this.value)" name="SELECT_Mood_30">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="hap">Happy</option>
    <option value="sad">Sadness</option>
    <option value="ang">Angry</option>
    <option value="gru">Grumpy</option>
</select>
<div id="show-these">
    <li></li>
    <li>Happy huh?</li>
    <li>Why so sad?</li>
    <li>Everything will be ok!</li>
    <li>Cheer up!</li>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(value){
        var option = $('.select').find('option[value="'+value+'"]');
        var index = $('.select').children().index(option);
        $('#show-these').children().hide();
        $($('#show-these').children()[index]).show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have access to add the `onchange="update(this.value)"` any other way to do it?